# Laravel 5.5 and sessions for subdomains?

Tags: php, laravel, session, laravel-5.5

I use subdomain routing in my app, there are set dynamic routes and every subdomain has its own login page, in `users` table are restrictions for `users & subdomains` and the validation works without problems, every user can login in his subdomain but not in others, this is as needed.

I'm a little confused, is this by default set different session per subdomain? I want to make possible for a user with more accounts to stay logged in more subdomains at the same moment, of course with separate data...

**Example:**

```
time.example.com -> time@example.com
finance.example.com -> finance@example.com
```

Session configuration is in my app by default, nothing I changed nothing.

This are 2 different subdomains and 2 different accounts, I want to be sure that this are also 2 different sessions...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try updating your `config/session.php`

Change from:

```
'domain' => null,
```

to (*The first period is important!*):

```
'domain' => '.example.com',
```

The default value will instruct the user's browser that their session cookie should only be accessible on the domain that it was created (`time.example.com`, etc.)

By putting a `.` in front of the domain name, you are instructing the browser that the cookie should be accessible on **any** subdomain.

Note that all of your users will be forced to log in again.

Comment: How I must implement it without being accessible to any domain ??

Comment: @NikolasDiakosavvas that is not possible, that would be a huge security flaw